# Bash Script changing ports lighttpd

Tags: centos

alright another question. Im writing a script to grab a port then replace it to put it in a configuration file. like for example.

if i cat this command.....(cat /var/log/lighttpd/access.log | tail -1)  and the last line is a number which is 12.
and then i want to (sed -i 's/8162/81 ????/' /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf) which replace port 8162 to/8112 of that output from cat (/var/log/lighttpd/access.log | tail -1) is 12. so basically its grabbing the output 12 then makes the new port 8112... how would I go about that, create a variable or what?? would awk be useful? or maybe some concantenate thing i should be doing. im not sure.  any thoughts or ideas???

Comment: The `12` is on the last line by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method:

1. Capture `12` in a variable: `var=$(cat /var/log/lighttpd/access.log | tail -1)`, then
2. Put that into the `sed` command:

   ```
   sed -i.bak "s/8162/81$var/" /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
   ```

   **OR**
3. Add the the `cat` command line to the sed at once, like so:

   ```
   sed -i.bak "s/8162/81$(cat /var/log/lighttpd/access.log | tail -1)/" /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
   ```

**WARNING**:

1. Always create a backup incase things go wrong with this syntax:

   ```
   sed -i.bak "s/8162/81$(cat /var/log/lighttpd/access.log | tail -1)/" /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
   ```
2. Note the `"` double quotes used, without which the command won't process your variable or `$(cat /var/log/lighttpd/access.log | tail -1)`

Comment: okay now another problem lol how would i apply that to selinux changing the port?? and also firewall would it be like - semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 81$var. and the firewall-cmd add-port=81$var/tcp -- permanent????????

Comment: I would think so please run a test and if not successful open a new question!